"The Mailer DSN is invalid" error in STAA.AGENCY SMTP setup
I am setting up an SMTP server at STAA.AGENCY profile. The website lets users set up their own smtp sever.
The error I see is, "MAILER DSN IS INVALID".
I have configured the Domain DNS, and tested the SMTP user using a Python script. The messages are being sent without fail. Any lead will be very much appreciated!
Click to view screenshot
